# $.parseXML() is not working in versions of IE greater than IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a issue using $.parseXML() with more version of IE8. Its working absolutely fine in IE8 and chrome as well as Firefox.  Please have a look on below given code.

**Jquery:**

```
        var result = data.d;
        var obj = decodeBase64(result);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(obj);
```

**XML returns:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    MultiLineItemJson>
    <Order_Number>PAAAA00017</Order_Number>
    <Order_Item>01</Order_Item>
    <Order_Subitem>0001</Order_Subitem>
    <Order_Type>PO</Order_Type>
    </MultiLineItemJson>
    </ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson>
```

**Error message in IE9**

```
Unhandled exception at line 490, column 3 in http://localhost:55005/resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.js

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid XML: 
<?xml version="1.0"?><ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><MultiLineItemJson><Order_Number>PAAAA00017</Order_Number><Order_Item>01</Order_Item></ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the value of `result`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I see the file is named 1.9.0 so if it realy is 1.9.0 it should not be a problem but jQuery 2 doesn't support IE 8 http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: @ Arun: Thanks for your response. The result is return xml as i mentioned in the question

Comment: @HMR: using jquery 1.9.0 it working fine for IE8 not for IE9

Comment: The xml you posted is not well formed but that would cause warnings in Firefox console (I use firebug). Checking in IE now

Comment: @HMR: What the issue with this xml??

Comment: Not sure, the xml you posted is not valid but would generate an error in FF and Chrome as well. I've posted an answer, you can try to make it work using a test.txt file containing the xml and try to parse that (assuming that data comes from an xhr request). I think it could be decodeBase64 works differently on IE so you should try console.log(obj) to make sure it's a valid xml string.

Comment: I see you opened bugs at jQuery but this is not a jQuery bug, the bug is in your code as parseXML works fine with valid xml. Maybe it's your base64. The bugs you posted are completely useless as they don't contain re producable code.

Comment: Your xml is invalid at the last closing tag, according to the error in IE9 your last closing tag is: `</ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson>` this should be `</MultiLineItemJson></ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson>` The strange thing is that it should not work with FF as well, are you sure you're checking the console and see if there are errors or are you assuming there are no errors because there is no error icon as in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that gives error can be traced to the jquery library code

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
parseXML: function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
},
```

the later browsers ie 9,10 return window.DOMParser  and the DOMParser(); object , and thus the code enters non-ie part .
But ie 8 does not have  DOMParser() defined , hence it throws error.

the fix would be add ie8 specific test alongwith if ( window.DOMParser )
Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Have to put this in an answer because it doesn't fit in a comment. I can't reproduce this on a windows machine.

js code:

```
    $.get("test.txt", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //var obj = decodeBase64(result);
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
        console.log(xmlDoc);
    });
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <MultiLineItemJson>
    <Order_Number>PAAAA00017</Order_Number>
    <Order_Item>01</Order_Item>
    <Order_Subitem>0001</Order_Subitem>
    <Order_Type>PO</Order_Type>
    </MultiLineItemJson>
    </ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson>
```

response header for test.txt: `Content-Type text/plain`

When renaming the `test.txt` to `test.xml` I get content type `text/xml` and all the code I need to get a document object from that is:

```
    $.get("test.xml", function (xmlDoc) {
        console.log(xmlDoc);
    });
```

When using the invalid XML you've posted then it would not work in FF as well since I get an error there.

I didn't use `decodeBase64` maybe you should test without that or console.log the text that it is returning (console.log(obj)). Press F12 in IE to open the developer tools and the console should be under the Script tab

Comment: xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" ); section catch the error. that means xml have the invalid format.But i can't understand what wrong with my xml??

Comment: @RajaAshutoshNayak console.log your xml and copy paste it in a new file. Open that file with any browser and it'll point out what's wrong with it. The xml you posted has a missing `>` in your ArrayOfMultiLineItemJson tag and a missing `<` in your MultiLineItemJson tag.